# How does fontspec actually work with the no-math attribute?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation that has different fonts for math and text.  As a MWE, when I write the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[
F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt
\]

\end{document}
```

what I would *expect* to see is regular text in Tahoma, and the math set in latin modern.  This seems to be what is implied by the documentation for fontspec.  However, when I run "xelatex myfile.tex", I see that the output file has Tahoma font throughout.  I have made similar attempts with mathspec and with the other commands like \setmainfont and the like, but I don't see what I'm supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an issue with `fontspec` but with how `beamer` sets up the fonts. By default, `beamer` makes all text sans serif, including the math text.  If you want serifed math and sans serif other text, use:

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

**Complete example**

```
 % !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Tahoma}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[
F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan!  One thing I am still confused about, however, is that this appears to say "use sans for text, and use serif for math".  What if I wanted to use different serif fonts for the two, e.g. Tahoma for text, and the usual Latin Modern Sans for math?

Comment: Why is the parentheses' spacing wrong in the example output? (Maybe we should leave out `\usepackage{lmodern}` or change it to `\usepackage{unicode-math}`?)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use:

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[
F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt
\]
\end{document}
```